# Understanding SQL queries: how to return the foreign table's information

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

I don't quite understand how SQL queries work when using relationships;

I am building a small math based flash card app. For the sake of efficiency and learning I'd like to not have duplicate questions and answers.

So, we end up with the following tables;

```
addition
questionId | answerId | info


question
id | num_a | num_b


answer
id | res
```

How do I return `[num_a, num_b, res, info]` ?

How do I select the addition questions with `num_a < x`  and `info = y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join:

```
select qu.num_a, qu.num_b, an.res, ad.info
from addition ad
inner join question qu on qu.id = ad.questionid
inner join answer an on an.id = qd.answerid
```

Then you can set up the filtering you want with a `where` clause:

```
where qu.num_a < x and ad.info = y
```

Of course `x` and `y` need to be proper literal values, whose datatype matches that of the table columns.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on GMB's answer re your second query - you can use a WHERE clause eg:

```
select qu.num_a, qu.num_b, an.res, ad.info
from addition ad
inner join question qu on qu.id = ad.questionid
inner join answer an on an.id = qd.answerid
WHERE qu.num_a < x AND ad.info = y
```